# Calculations of elements of S5 in cycle notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Hi I have an exam very close, and I would appreciate if anyone could answer the queries that I have for these questions.

**I particularly need clarifcation for iii v and vi.**

The general question that I have is to:

Perform the following calculations of elements of S5 in cycle notation:

(i) (21534)^-1

(ii) (5124)^2

(iii) (45).(34).(45)

(iv) (12)^(45)

v) ((154)(23))^7

vi) ((12).(23).(34).(45))^5

So for:

i) Quite straightforward, just flip the bracket round so that it reads: (43512).

ii) Again easy. (5124)^2 = (5124)(5124). Evaluating this has:
(52)(14)

iii) I have reservations about the . used here, how does the dot differ as to if it was expressed as: (45)(34)(45) Would there be any difference?
I have the final answer being (4)(53) so (53).

iv) I am not completely familiar with these types. If it is of the form A^B, then this is equivalent to B^-1 AB right?
So (12)^(45) becomes (54)(12)(45) which is simply (12)

v) Since the elements within the brackets are not repeated I have this as (154)(23).

vi) Although I consider that I have the correct answer as (45123) I am unsure of how this is really achieved. The power is negligent in most cases, in cycle notation it goes from right to left:

So by starting at 4, this goes to 5. But do we stop there or go all the way back around to get 1. Then stop - or go all the way back around to get 2 ergo 3.

Any help would be so appreciated. Thanks

If I have posted this incorrectly or tagged it wrong, I'm sorry. I am relatively new to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to help you with (vi), which I believe will be the most useful for you.

To evaluate:

$[(1\ 2)(2\ 3)(3\ 4)(4\ 5)]^5$, let's evaluate what's "inside" the brackets, first.

Working right-to-left, we see that:

$1 \to 1 \to 1 \to 1 \to 2$ (only the last transposition (on the left) moves $1$).

$2 \to 2 \to 2 \to 3 \to 3$ (the penultimate transposition moves $2$, but the last one doesn't move $3$).

$3 \to 3 \to 4 \to 4 \to 4$

$4 \to 5 \to 5 \to 5 \to 5$

$5 \to 4 \to 3 \to 2 \to 1.$

We can re-write this as $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$, a $5$-cycle, so:

$[(1\ 2)(2\ 3)(3\ 4)(4\ 5)]^5 = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)^5 = e$.

Comment: Thank you I see how this is achieved, and this seems logical. May I ask in your very last line, e is the identity right? so is e always equal to all the elements in order of thier group i.e. this is S5, ergo 12345^n = e, where n is 5 here?

Comment: Yes,$e$ is the identity. In $S_n$ for any positive integer $n$, any $n$-cycle to the $n$-th power is the identity. You can see this in the following way: an $n$ cycle to the first power, each number maps to the successive number in the cycle. For a square you "skip one", for a cube, you "skip two", and so on, so that for an $n$-th power, each number is mapped back to itself.